# Sort mongoDB documents in a specific manner

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have been trying to sort documents according to their status. I have documents with three status
a. NACK
b. ACK
c. RES

i want the documents to be in this order : NACK -> ACK -> RES. these incidents should also be sorted according to their creation date so that the latest one should appear on the top then followed by others.

I tried doing it with the aggregation pipeline. the query i used is as follows

```js
let sortedIncidents = await Incident.aggregate([
    { $match: query },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            status: 1
        }
    },
    {$addFields: {
        sortField: {$cond: [{$eq: [ "$status", "NACK"]}, 1,
            {$cond: [{$eq: ["$status", "ACK"]}, 2,
            3]} ]}
    }},
    { $sort: sortField: 1} },
    { $skip: pagination.skip },
    { $limit: pagination.perPage },
])
```

it does sorts the documents according to their status but it shuffles their order of creation.

Comment: you should change your sort query to `{sortField: 1, createdAt: 1}`
On another note, be careful with skip-limit pagination, it doesn't scale well if you have a lot of records.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please upload text rather than images in the future as it makes it much easier for us to assist.  What is the field containing their order of creation? Add that to the specification passed to `$sort`.  Something like `{ $sort: { sortField: 1, timestampField: -1 } }`. You can swap the order of those two fields or change the creation field to be ascending.